# Context omega with Omega 4 not rendering block

Tags: theming, 7

I have Omega 4 installed along with the Context omega module. I am trying to add a context based on my path to add two blocks to the template. I am working on a development server and based my context off one already working on the server, so I know the issue isn't with the path. However, when I save the context and go to the path, the two blocks that should appear in the header and first sidebar are not being pulled. I checked the code and it isn't there so it's not a styling issue. I flushed all caches and still nothing. Anyone have any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: In looking further into this, I reverted the theme to an old non-omega theme and the context block worked. I re-enabled my omega subtheme and the block disappeared. I then disabled the subtheme layout using only context and the block appeared. There's a conflict somewhere with my subtheme layout and the context omega module.